# How to keep a value in a json field I don't want to modify

Tags: java, json, spring, postman

I have an entity named Absence and I'm doing the Controller for Spring and testing with Postman. Now I'm doing a PUTMaping to edit two fields, 'dateMissing' and 'comment', the thing is that I can edit both at once through the json body (finding the absence i want to edit by ID) in Postman like that:

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "dateMissing": "1574856138888",
    "comment": "she/he was ill" 
}
```

But, here is the problem, when I want just to edit one of this two fields, the other one is set to null and I want to preserve the original value(not losing its value and not setting it to null!) if its not edited with a JSON Body like this one, excluding comment:

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "dateMissing": "1574856138888"
}
```

Here is my Absence Entity code: (you'll see the @JsonInclude anotation that I think it's not the solution what i'm searching for...)

```
@Entity
public class Absence {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
    @Id
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private int id;

    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)
    private Date dateMissing; 

//  @JsonInclude(value=Include.ALWAYS, content=Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)
    private String comment; 

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @JoinColumn (name="student_id")
//  @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    private MyAppUser userStudent;

    public Absence() {

    }
    public Absence(Date dateMissing, String comment) {

        this.comment = comment;
        this.dateMissing = dateMissing;
    }

//getters and setters...

    public Date getDateMissing() {
        return dateMissing;
    }

    public void setDateMissing(Date dateMissing) {
        this.dateMissing = dateMissing;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }
}
```

And here is my PUT Mapping:

```
    // Edit Absence by id
    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)
    @PutMapping("api/students/absences")
    public Absence putAbsence(@RequestBody @Valid Absence absence) {

        // if AbsenceRepo is not empty...
        if (!myAbsenceRepository.findAll().isEmpty()) {

            Absence absenceToEdit = myAbsenceRepository.findOneById(absence.getId());

                absenceToEdit.setComment(absence.getComment());
                absenceToEdit.setDateMissing(absence.getDateMissing());

            myAbsenceRepository.save(absenceToEdit);

            return absenceToEdit;

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Thanks to you all!!

Comment: There is no point checking if myAbsenceRepository.findAll() is empty. Instead just do the single lookup for Absence by findOneById and check if its null. This will prevent 2 lookups. Also, can you please post your setter methods? Also, is it possible the absence getComment and getDateMissing are returning null? Check if they are.

Comment: *"[if] set to null [...] I want to preserve the original value"* Easy, the solution is this very advanced statement called an `if` statement, which can be used to only update the value when the new value is not null, like this: `if (absence.getComment() != null) { absenceToEdit.setComment(absence.getComment()); }` --- If that's not the solution, then edit the question and clarify what your problem is.

Comment: There you have the getters and setters already ;) @jason

Comment: *Also, is it possible the absence getComment and getDateMissing are returning null? Check if they are.*

Comment: @jason no, because when I edit both fields at once they are working fine, the problem is when I just want to edit one of this two fields, then the other one is setted to null.

Comment: @Jaykooh Look what Andreas said above.

Comment: I already did a logic like that: 
`
   if (!dateToEdit.equalsIgnoreCase("") || !dateToEdit.equalsIgnoreCase(null)) {

    absenceToEdit.setDateMissing(absence.getDateMissing());

   } else if (!commentToEdit.equalsIgnoreCase("") || !commentToEdit.equalsIgnoreCase(null)) {

    absenceToEdit.setComment(absence.getComment());

   } 
   else {

    absenceToEdit.setComment(absence.getComment());
    absenceToEdit.setDateMissing(absence.getDateMissing());
   }
`
but it just works for the Comment field, the date field returns me a 500 status error
@jason @andreas

Comment: @Andreas What you are saying is not working due to that i don't want to set the JSON empty like that: {"comment": "" }, I want to erase that field from the JSON body in Postman, and neither null or equal("") works...

Comment: @Jaykooh What does "not works" mean? If you omit the JSON field in Postman, what happens? --- If you get an error saying it's not allowed to be null, then it's likely because of the `@Valid` annotation. Try removing that, or add `@Nullable` to the two fields. Of course, that could be misleading if you don't want the database columns to be nullable, but that's because you're misusing a DAO object as a controller DTO object.

Comment: @Andreas When I omit the json field Postman returns me this: {
    "timestamp": 1586967170728,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/students/absences"
} and I'm trying to learn, I just have 3 months programming

Comment: @Jaykooh Try looking at the log file for the real error message.